# Spring CGLIB AopProxy interferes with Jersey resource method parameter validation

Tags: java, spring, jersey, aop

Stack is Spring Boot w/ Jetty/Jersey.  Here's the resource method in question:

```
@GET
@Path("campaignTargets")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public List<CampaignTargetOutputDTO> getCampaignTargets(
        @PathParam("businessUnitId") Integer id,
        @QueryParam("name") String name,
        @Pattern(regexp = DATE_VALIDATION_PATTERN) @QueryParam("startDate") String startDate,
        @Pattern(regexp = DATE_VALIDATION_PATTERN) @QueryParam("endDate") String endDate,
        @Pattern(regexp = INTEGER_CSV_VALIDATION_PATTERN) @QueryParam("targetTypeIds") String targetTypeIds,
        @Pattern(regexp = ALPHANUM_CSV_VALIDATION_PATTERN) @QueryParam("statuses") String statuses) {
    return ResourceUtil.entityOr404(campaignService.getAdvertiserCampaignTargets(id, name, startDate, endDate, targetTypeIds, statuses));
}
```

When Jersey intercepts the call to this method to perform the validation, it doesn't (always) get this method.  The reason I know this is because I have taken the advice of the [Jersey documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html#d0e13322) and created the following `ValidationConfig`:

```
@Provider
public class ValidationConfigurationContextResolver implements
        ContextResolver<ValidationConfig> {

    @Context
    private ResourceContext resourceContext;

    @Override
    public ValidationConfig getContext(Class<?> type) {
        final ValidationConfig config = new ValidationConfig();
        config.constraintValidatorFactory(
                resourceContext.getResource(InjectingConstraintValidatorFactory.class));
        config.parameterNameProvider(new CustomParameterNameProvider());
        return config;
    }

    private static class CustomParameterNameProvider extends DefaultParameterNameProvider {

        private static final Pattern PROXY_CLASS_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(.*?)\\$\\$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB\\$\\$.*$");
        public CustomParameterNameProvider() {
        }

        @Override
        public List<String> getParameterNames(Method method) {

            /*
             * Since we don't have a full object here, there's no good way to tell if the method we are receiving 
             * is from a proxy or the resource object itself.  Proxy objects have a class containing the string
             * $$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ followed by some random digits.  These proxies don't have the same annotations
             * on their method params as their targets, so they can actually interfere with this parameter naming.
             */
            String className = method.getDeclaringClass().getName();
            Matcher m = PROXY_CLASS_PATTERN.matcher(className);
            if(m.matches()) {
                try {
                    return getParameterNames(method.getDeclaringClass().getSuperclass().
                            getMethod(method.getName(), method.getParameterTypes()));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return super.getParameterNames(method);
                }
            }
            Annotation[][] annotationsByParam = method.getParameterAnnotations();
            List<String> paramNames = new ArrayList<>(annotationsByParam.length);
            for(Annotation[] annotations : annotationsByParam) {
                String name = getParamName(annotations);
                if(name == null) {
                    name = "arg" + (paramNames.size() + 1);
                }
                paramNames.add(name);
            }
            return paramNames;
        }

        private String getParamName(Annotation[] annotations) {
            for(Annotation annotation : annotations) {
                if(annotation.annotationType() == QueryParam.class) {
                    return ((QueryParam) annotation).value();
                } else if(annotation.annotationType() == PathParam.class) {
                    return ((PathParam) annotation).value();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

My main problem with this solution is that it requires a paragraph of comment to (hopefully) prevent future confusion.  Otherwise it seems to work.  Without this, I get uninformative parameter names like `arg1` and so on, which I'd like to avoid.  Another big problem with this solution is that it relies too heavily on the implementation of Aop proxying in Spring.  The pattern may change and break this code at some point in the future and I may not be here to explain this code when the comment fails to illuminate its purpose.  The weirdest thing about this is that it seems to be intermittent.  Sometimes the parameter names are good and sometimes they're not.  Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this happens as a result of running the server from eclipse.  I haven't quite figured out why, but running the server from the command line fixes the problem.  If anyone can figure out why eclipse does this and how to turn off whatever "feature" of eclipse is causing this, I will upvote/accept your answer.  For now the answer is, don't run the service in eclipse.